# Attribute not updated in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Rails version: 4.2.3

I am into a strange situation here, I think it is a silly thing, but I dont know why this happens.

I receive a post notification on a URL, something like /accounts/payment. After process the json I received, I need do a update on a attribute of model Account. I am  doing something like this:

```
account.update_columns(status: "delayed")
```

or `update_attributes`

everything works fine locally. All tests pass. But for a unknown reason when this code run in production, the attribute is not updated.

here some logs from production env.

```
SQL (1.7ms)  UPDATE "accounts" SET "status" = 'delayed' WHERE "accounts"."type" IN ('StandardAccount') AND "accounts"."id" = $1  [["id", 94]]


Account.find(94).status
  Account Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "accounts".* FROM "accounts" WHERE "accounts"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 94]]
 => "actived"
```

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE 1**
My modal schema is:

```
StandardAccount < Account
```

**UPDATE 2**
Not a Rails problem. I found a Trigger on DB involved with accounts table and cause the problem.

Comment: Maybe your account with id 94 in production is not of `StandardAccount` type. What does `Account.find(94).type` returns to you in both enviroments?

Comment: Hi @MurifoX. same type in both enviroments  ```Account.find(94).type #=> StandardAccount```

Comment: If you run `account.update_columns(status: "delayed")` on the production console, does it return some `ActiveRecord` errors or does it update the `status`? Maybe there's some kind of filter in your model or validation that fails.

Comment: Please check the return value of `account.update_columns(status: "delayed")` or use `update_attributes!` that throws an exception if the record wasn't saved.

Comment: @MurifoX on the production console everything works fine.

Comment: @spickermann no errors where use ```update_attributes˜```

Comment: @elf: That was not my question, because `update_attributes` usually does not throw exceptions. I would like to know if `update_attributes` returns `true` or `false`? And if `update_attibutes!` (note the `!`) throws an error.

Comment: @spickermann I use ```update_attributes!```. (typo in the previous comment). and yes, return true.

Comment: I just execute a query direct on postgres and the column is not updated. (but log UPDATE 1)

Comment: Seems like a problem with your postgres database.

Comment: Did you make sure that production has the necessary migrations and that you ran all needed tasks?

Comment: Yes @TamerShlash. I found a Trigger on DB involved with accounts table and cause the problem. Thanks

Comment: Triggers are almost always a bad thing when they try to implement business logic. They have a bad name for it even in the database world.

Comment: @elf, if you solved your problem it's usually good to post an answer outlining what the solution was. (for future people, e.t.c.)

Comment: @MikeH-R I added Updated 2 that indicates that the problem is with a trigger.

Comment: @elf, that's good, normally it'd be posted as an answer, but if the informations there I guess that's alright.